# How can I copy out of emacs in terminal emulator with Wayland?

Tags: copy-paste

I often run Emacs in terminal emulator by `emacs -nw`.

When using Wayland/Sway, how can I copy a text region out of Emacs to another window?

When I use Ubuntu with X, I can do that by selecting the region, then <kbd>M-|</kbd> and typing `xsel -bi`.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/bugaevc/wl-clipboard? what else have you tried?